# Assigning Column Value from Function

Tags: admin, grid

Creating a custom module that has a grid in admin. I'm trying to assign the value of a function to be the column value. The hard part is the $columnid as what I want doesn't have an attribute in the db.

Here's my add column section:

```
   $this->addColumn(
        '',
        array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Amount Sold (Monthly)'),
            'index'  => $this->getSalesOverMonth()
        )
    );
```

and my getSalesOverMonth function:

```
public function getSalesOverMonth() {
    $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of this month'));
    $to   = date('Y-m-d');

    $sku = $this->getSku();

    $qty = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty($from, $to)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
        ->getFirstItem();

    return (int) $qty;
}
```

that function does actually return the correct value but I can't plug it into the table

any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Answer I found was to create a custom column renderer that takes the function data and returns it

example of my one for anyone looking for a solution to their problem:

```
// app/code/local/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Render/Column.php
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Render_Column extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $block   = Mage::getBlockSingleton('company_module/adminhtml_grid');
        $monthly = $block->getSalesOverMonth($row->getData('sku'));
        $weekly  = $monthly / 4;

        if ($monthly == 0) {
            return '0';
        } else {
            return $weekly;
        }
    }
}
```

Main Block File:

```
// app/code/local/Company/Module/Block/Grid.php
$this->addColumn(
    'columnid',
     array(
         'header'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Table Header'),
         'index'    => 'field_id',
         'renderer' => 'Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Render_Column'
     )
);
```